# How do I write a Makefile to run a build process where the target filenames aren't known in advance, but after the firststep?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Context:** I have a build process whose first step generates ~20k files with unpredictable, but deterministic filenames. The remaining steps operate per file, and generate new files with the same name but different extensions.

A simplified shell version of the build process could look like:

```
./generate_testcases spec.json # Generates many .txt files
find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ./run_test_case {} \; # Generates a .log file for each .txt file
find -type f -name '*.log' -exec ./grab_test_data {} \; # Generates a .csv file for each .log file
```

I'd like to do this in `make` for several reasons, but particularly because the second two steps are prone to failures, and it would be nice to just run `make` another time and have it only run the steps on the files that actually need it.

The steps themselves are fairly trivial with pattern rules:

```
%.txt : spec.json
    ./generate_testcases spec.json
%.log : %.txt
    ./run_test_case $<
%.csv : %.log
    ./grab_test_data $<
```

---

**The problem is that I have no way of defining the build target (e.g. an `all`) until the first step has run. I do not have control over the first step, and cannot get the list of filenames in advance.**

---

I first tried [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) with a `$$(shell find ...)` for the prerequisites, but even that is run too early, since make has to do the second expansion to build the dependency tree before running any recipes.

I then thought why not use some kind of marker `file_list` to get the first step to run if there are no files present at all, and grab the list of `.txt` files from that file for future runs:

```
text_files := $(shell cat file_list)

.PHONY: all
all : file_list $(text_files)

file_list : spec.json
   ./generate_testcases spec.json
   find -type f -name '*.txt' > file_list

%.txt : spec.json
   ./generate_testcases spec.json
   find -type f -name '*.txt' > file_list
```

There are some problems here, including the fact that the `file_list` can potentially include old files that are no longer generated by a new `spec.json`, but I'm willing to live with that, for now. This idea also doesn't help with the second two steps; it doesn't give me a way to add the `.log` and `.csv` files to the `all` target.

---

My next thought was, "well, I can just run make twice", and I can do that programmatically in the `Makefile` itself:

```
text_files := $(shell cat file_list 2> /dev/null || true)
log_files := $(patsubst %.txt,%.log,$(text_files))
csv_files := $(patsubst %.txt,%.csv,$(text_files))

.PHONY: all
all : file_list $(text_files) $(log_files) $(csv_files)

file_list : spec.json
   ./generate_testcases spec.json
   find -type f -name '*.txt' > file_list
   $(MAKE)

%.txt : spec.json
   ./generate_testcases spec.json
   find -type f -name '*.txt' > file_list
   $(MAKE)
%.log : %.txt
    ./run_test_case $<
%.csv : %.log
    ./grab_test_data $<
```

When nothing exists, `file_list` will still be created, and `make` will be called again. The child `make` will have a `file_list` so `text_files` and the other dependent variables will be populated, and the rest of the build will run as desired. If `file_list` is up to date, but other pieces are missing, then the first `make` will take care of the other steps, without running the child `make`.

The problem is when both `file_list` is outdated, and there are missing pieces with respect to the outdated `file_list`: `file_list` will get updated, the child `make` will get called on that and run everything, but then the parent `make` will still run the outdated build steps it thinks it needs due to the old `file_list`.

I can probably live with these issues, but I'd like to resolve them if possible easily. **Is there a better way of doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of invoking a sub-make is definitely the simplest and most clear way to handle this.

To avoid things getting built multiple times, you just need to not have the top-makefile depend on any of the final outputs, and always invoke the sub-make.  It would be something like this:

```
text_files := $(shell cat file_list 2> /dev/null)
log_files := $(patsubst %.txt,%.log,$(text_files))
csv_files := $(patsubst %.txt,%.csv,$(text_files))

.PHONY: all
all : file_list
        $(MAKE) _build_inner

file_list : spec.json
        ./generate_testcases $<
        find -type f -name '*.txt' > $@

.PHONY: _build_inner
_build_inner: $(log_files) $(csv_files)

  ...
```

Comment: If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU Make you can use the `$(file ...)` function to avoid invoking `$(shell cat ...)`